# Call Java Class from JIRA Web Panel

Tags: java, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

How to call a JAVA class from a Web Panel in Jira with velocity?
I want to create a right panel that can toggle a button to callback a java class.

templates/random-indicator.vm:

```
<button class="aui-button aui-button-link">Toggle Button</button>
```

atlassia-plugin.xml

```
<web-panel name="randomIndicator" i18n-name-key="random-indicator.name" key="random-indicator" location="atl.jira.view.issue.right.context" weight="1000"> 
    <description key="random-indicator.description">random Indicator</description>  
    <context-provider class="random.jira.random.plugin.randomIndicator"/>  
    <resource name="view" type="velocity" location="templates/random-indicator.vm"/> 
    <label key="random-indicator.title"/>
</web-panel>
```

randomindicator.java

```
package random.jira.random.plugin;

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.webfragment.contextproviders.AbstractJiraContextProvider;
import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.webfragment.model.JiraHelper;
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;

public class randomIndicator extends AbstractJiraContextProvider {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getContextMap(ApplicationUser applicationUser, JiraHelper jiraHelper) {
        Map<String, Object> contextMap = new HashMap<>();
        Issue currentIssue = (Issue) jiraHelper.getContextParams().get("issue");
        Timestamp dueDate = currentIssue.getDueDate();
        if (dueDate != null) {
            LocalDate currentTimeInDays = LocalDate.now();
            LocalDate dueDateTimeInDays = dueDate.toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate();
            long daysAwayFromDueDateCalc = DAYS.between(currentTimeInDays, dueDateTimeInDays);
            contextMap.put("daysAwayFromDueDate", daysAwayFromDueDateCalc);
        }
        return contextMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to achieve this is with a javascript http client running in the velocity template and a Java Servlet.

The Java Servlet can run side by side with the plugin.

The full tutorial to create a servlet for jira is [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/creating-a-jira-issue-crud-servlet-and-issue-search/)

Comment: What if I need to work at WebPanel itself? So, for example, I need to pass data from Java Class to an HTML, which is on the jira.view.issue page WebPanel? Do you say this is impossible?